# Cannot import python module windows

Tags: python-2.7, import, pip

I have a generally working python installation, and I attempted to install `librabbitmq`.

Here is the output from pip:

```
Downloading/unpacking librabbitmq
Running setup.py (path:d:\daniel\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Daniel\librabbitmq\setup.py)egg_info for package librabbitmq

warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'tests'
no previously-included directories found matching '*.pyc'
no previously-included directories found matching '*.o'
no previously-included directories found matching '*.la'
no previously-included directories found matching '*.so'
no previously-included directories found matching '*.dylib'
Installing collected packages: librabbitmq
Running setup.py install for librabbitmq

warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'tests'
no previously-included directories found matching '*.pyc'
no previously-included directories found matching '*.o'
no previously-included directories found matching '*.la'
no previously-included directories found matching '*.so'
no previously-included directories found matching '*.dylib'
Successfully installed librabbitmq
```

When I try to import it in a python file, it gives:

```
ImportError: No module named librabbitmq
```

Things I have already checked:

1. I am using version 2.7, and the downloaded package is for version 2.7
2. The permissions on the folder/files stored in `C:\Anaconda\libs\site-packages` give enough access
3. That folder is on my path
4. It has the same format as other python packages that were egg files, and those work

What could the issue be?

**Update:**

Here is where I am at: I have the rabbitmq dll file built, and in the path. I converted the `connection.c` file to compile by changing `unistd.h` to `winsock2.h`. I am now getting the error:

```
fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'python27.lib'
```

I have no idea how to fix that.

Since it turns out that windows is not actually supported, I will also accept as an answer any python module that interfaces with rabbitmq that does so though some C module interface (or something equivalently as fast. I have profiled, and my code currently spends 80% of its time inside pika and that is not acceptable)

Comment: Is there a `C:\Anaconda\libs\site-packages\librabbitmq` folder with contents (at least an `__init__.py` file)? Do you have any other Python installations on your computer?

Comment: @MattDMo The folder is there, but its an egg package, so I have a bunch of text files, and `not-zip-safe` and `PKG-INFO` file.

Every other installed package works

Comment: No, there should be a `librabbitmq` folder, as well as a file or folder named something along the lines of `librabbitmq-1.2.3-py2.7.egg-info`. If the `.egg-info` is a directory, and contains a `not-zip-safe` file, then there **has** to be another folder with the actual module's contents in it. If there isn't, something went wrong with the installation.

Comment: @MattDMo There isn't. Where can I find out what happened?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how much help this will actually be, but have you considered using virtualenv to help wrangle your libraries? It may not be the direct solution to your problem, but it could possibly resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Ive seen a question similar to this before if im not mistaken you need to tell the linker were to find the library, Linker->General->Additional Library Directories

Hope this helps. best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

For the Update: Are you sure that you have modified the library path to C:\Anaconda\libs\python27.lib .
The default path it might be looking for will be C:\Python27\libs\python27.lib.